# how to find all the urls/ pages on mysite.com

Tags: web, dotnetnuke

i have a website that i now support and need to list all live pages/ url's.
is there a crawler i can use to point to my homepage and have it list all the pages/url's that it finds.

then i can delete any that dont make their way into this listing as they will be orphan pages/url's that have never been cleaned up?

I am using DNN and want to kill un-needed pages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a database-driven CMS, you should be able to do this either via the DNN admin interface or by looking directly in the database. Far more reliable than a crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the old days I used [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) for this exact purpose, using its recursive retrieval functionality.  It might not be the most efficient way, but it was definitely effective.  YMMV, of course, since some sites will return a *lot* more content than others.